# Sign PDF form with iTextSharp like a PDF signature

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext, cac

Rather than save a file and then sign it I am filling the data fields with a stamper in a memory stream.

```
MemoryStream fs = GetSaarForm();
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fs.ToArray(), null);
            string pwd = ""; 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pwd))
                pwd = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(20, 5);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms, '\0', false))
                {
                    stamper.SetEncryption(
                        null,
                        System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd),
                        PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY,
                        PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
                    AcroFields form = stamper.AcroFields;
                    StampSaarPdf(form, candidate, saar);

                }
                //SaveSaarPassword(candidateId, pwd);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
```

Stamping the individual fields is in the method.  But the signatures are the problem.  They have to look like the attached.

[image: visible signature]

I've looked over all of the ways that people have done the signature and just cannot see how I can do this.  This is a DOD CAC signature.  Does anyone have any ideas?  There are four separate signatures I have to put in the form.  I changed the signature fields to be a plain textbox.

Comment: You need to use the `X509Certificate2` from the DoD CAC card.

Comment: *"I changed the signature fields to be a plain textbox"* - if you want to sign the document, why do you change signature fields to textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Java applet because it has to be signed at the client level using ActivClient as the CAC middleware.